# Description photo viewer in GUI - Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new in Python, I am searching for solution with this error. I got stuck with this assignment.

I'm trying to change the description by each picture but unfortunately I failed.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.title("Image Viewer")
root.config(bg = "Grey")

frame1 = Frame(root, width = 500, height = 325, bg = "Silver")
frame1.pack(side = TOP)
frame2 = Frame(root, width = 500, height = 25, borderwidth= 1, bg = "Grey")
frame2.pack(side = BOTTOM, pady= 2)

# Image:
img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("dec19.jpg"))
img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("dec20.jpg"))
img3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("dec21.jpg"))

# Description:
des1= Label(frame1, text = "I am happy this day")
des2= Label(frame1, text = "going somewhere")
des3= Label(frame1, text = "Today is a great day")

# , width = 500, height = 315
num = 1
# List:
img_list = [img1, img2,img3]
des_list = [1 , 2, 3]

# Startup:
my_label = Label(frame1,image = img1)
my_label.pack()
my_des = Label(frame1, text = f"Description{num}")
my_des.pack(side = BOTTOM)

#  Definning Command functions:
def close_app():
    exit()

def forward(image_num):
    global my_label
    global prev
    global next1
    global num
    global my_des
    global des_list

    my_label.pack_forget()
    # .grid_forget()
    my_label = Label(frame1, image= img_list[image_num-1])
    my_label.pack()

    my_des.pack_forget()
    my_des = Label(frame1, text = f"Description{des_list[image_num-1]}")
    my_des.pack()
    # .grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
    next1  = Button(frame2, text = "Next", command = lambda: forward(image_num+1))
    next1.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
    prev = Button(frame2, text = "Previous", command = lambda : back(image_num-1))
    prev.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

    if image_num == 3:
        next1 = Button(frame2, text = "Next", state = DISABLED)
        next1.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

prev = Button(frame2, text = "Previous", state = DISABLED, command =lambda : back(2))
prev.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
exits = Button(frame2, text = "Exit", command = close_app)
exits.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
next1 = Button(frame2, text = "Next", command = lambda: forward(2))
next1.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: can you explain better the problem and the expected results?

Comment: i want to change the description together with the picture if i click next but in my case only picture change but not descrption

Comment: actually i tried the code that you have posted and when i click the next button the description goes from `This is image 1` to `Description 2` so it works

Comment: @Mat.C thanks for your review, kindly chance the code into something like this des1= Label(frame1, text = "i am happy today") it will not appears

Comment: @Mat.C kindly review again my code i change some details. if you can see the description not change instead just add number in last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that each description is different you can create a dictionary wher you bind each image index to its description

```
image_description = {
    1 : 'I am happy this day',
    2 : "going somewhere",
    3: "Today is a great day"
}
```

Now that you have this dictionary when you call the function that changes the image instead having a static string that changes only the number ( `f"Description{des_list[image_num-1]}"` ) you can get the datas from the dictionary

so change this 3 lines

```
my_des.pack_forget()
my_des = Label(frame1, text = f"Description{des_list[image_num-1]}")
my_des.pack()
```

to this

```
my_des.configure(text = f"{image_description[image_num]}")
```

Comment: Glad that it helped